# Email address validation in System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am sending email with `System.Net.Mail` via `.Net`. When email address contains dot like john.smith@company.com, in my computer it works with `Visual Studio Development Server`, but in the production which runs `.Net 4.0.30319` integrated mode it throws format exception. Any comments why it can be?

I used following code:

```
ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(MailAddress).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) }, null);

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
string[] arrMailTo = To.Split('@');
mm.To.Add ((MailAddress)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { To, arrMailTo[0], arrMailTo[1] }));
```

Comment: Yeah. Here is my idea - learn to provide a full error report. I generally vote to close on people not willing to copy/paste the full exception information and mark the line the error occurs.

Comment: I already wrote that System.FormatException was thrown. Error occurs in last line of code. I tried also adding using without invoking the constructor like: new mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("john.smith@company.com"))

Comment: Well, you need to learn. I fail to see how that can work given that what you put into the invoke in your example code totally does not match any of the constructors. Are you sure about the .NET version? Given that most updates released ro 4.0 show the same version as they are in place updates (as much as this is confusing, sadly)?

Comment: Well, you need to also change your arrogant style of typing. I installed the version `4.5.2` into the server. During debugs with my dev machine & `Visual Studio 2015 Update 1` this constructor works with following parameters: email address, user name and domain, email is being sent. Problem is in production environment, it just throws "System.FormatException" that email format is not good.